# Android Studio - Create New Android Virtual Device with lower version

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a new Android Emulator using Android Studio 0.8.6. When I try to create one in AVD Manager, the only option in target menu is 'Android 4.4W - API Level 20'. The option has failed the execution of my developing application based on 4.1.

I've gone through some documentation and couldn't find a way to add a target. Anyone can give a suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your SDK Manager and download the desired API then create a new AVD or Edit the existing one

[image]

Check your 4.1 API version and hit download
[image]